# Fullcalendar & RRule access toText

Tags: fullcalendar-5, rrule

I'm using Fullcalendar v5.6 with RRule for recurring events.
The events are being generated correctly on the calendar but I'd like to be able to access the toText function so I can display human readable text - similar to how the demo works https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/

I've tried but I'm unable to access the function from Fullcalendar.
The closest I've come is with this code from the eventClick event

```
eventClick: function(info) {
console.log(info.event._def.recurringDef.typeData.rruleSet.toText());
}
```

This just shows 'every year' on the console, so isn't working.

Is it possible to access this function from Fullcalendar?

**UPDATE**
Here's a codepen which displays the issue I am facing.

https://codepen.io/damiantaylor/pen/rNdmaQg

When clicking on an event, the console will show the rrule object but there seems to be a problem with the data. 'freq' is zero, 'dtstart' is shown as today and 'until' is null.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this just fullcaldendar/rrule not playing nicely?